# I can't load libraries into Rstudio

Tags: r

Summary of problem: I install packages successfully but my libraries will not load. This problem has only happened recently.

What steps have I taken?: I uninstalled and reinstalled Rstudio. I uninstalled and reinstalled the packages I want while setting dependencies = TRUE.

Whenever I try to load the library of an installed package, I get this error message:

```
> library(nycflights13)
> flights
```

> Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) :    DLL ‘cli’ not
> found: maybe not installed for this architecture?

I've gotten this error message for every package I've tried to use in R.

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.1

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you don't have a dependency installed. I would suggest trying  the answer provided, or at least `install.packages("nycflights13", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: I updated R to version 4.1.1 and installed the package with dependencies, but I got the same error when I tried loading the library.

Comment: What OS version are you using? Seems related to: https://community.rstudio.com/t/dll-not-found-maybe-not-installed-for-this-architecture/54734 but what was involved there was reinstalling dependencies. It's unclear how you might have got to this state though. You haven't just copied libraries from one computer to another or anything, have you?

Comment: No, I haven't copied libraries from one computer to another. 

I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling everything. I'll see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked to see if the package is installed in your actual R directory? If it isn't in there, try installing it again, using `destdir`.

```
install.packages("nycflights13", destdir = "C:\your-pathway-to\R\win-library\your-version-of-R", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Still pretty new at this myself, so apologies if it doesn't work . This is what I would try next though.

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. I get the same error when loading libraries

Comment: Bizarre. Do you get the error messages when you run it in actual R, not RStudio?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try running it in actual R.